# Django urls.py syntax error (maybe importing issues?)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm using django framework and I'm experiencing an error.
this is my settings.py, INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps',
)
```

and, this is my apps/ directory.

```
apps/
    __init__.py
    qnaBoard/
        admin.py
        migrations/
        tests.py
        views.py
        urls.py
        __init__.py
        models.py
        urls.py
```

and, this is my urls.py, which is located in the same directory with settings.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^course/', include('apps.qnaBoard.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I think I followed the right way, but, it says it cannot find apps.qnaBoard.urls, and raises syntax error.

This is traceback :

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/root/campusmate/campusmate/campusmate/urls.py" in <module>
  9.     url(r'^course/', include('apps.qnaBoard.urls')), #need to apply course router
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  28.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /course/
Exception Value: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 4)
```

and this is apps/qnaBoard/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from apps.qnaBoard.views import showPost
from apps.qnaBoard.views import showQuestionThread
from apps.qnaBoard.views import writeReply
from apps.qnaBoard.views import writeQuestion
from apps.qnaBoard.views.import writeAnswer

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'campusmate.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    # need to be refactored when course router are attached.
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/([1-4])/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/article/list/', showPost.as_view()),
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/([1-4])/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/article/([0-9]+)/$', showQuestionThread.as_view()),
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/([1-4])/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/article/([0-9]+)/reply', writeReply.as_view()),
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/([1-4])/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/article/write/$', writeQuestion.as_view()),
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/([1-4])/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/article/write/([0-9]+)/$', writeAnswer.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: Can you show us `apps/qnaBoard/urls.py`?

Comment: yes, update `apps/qnaBoard/urls.py` file also. I think you miss something  in this file.

Comment: `apps` is not a valid django application. `INSTALLED_APPS` contains a list of django application ( not just any python module ). Reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/ . In your example, make sure `qnaBoard` qualifies as a django application, and then add `apps.qnaBoard` to `INSTALLED_APPS` .

Comment: I doubt that it is relevant but `/list/` and '/reply' should end with `/$`.

Answer (score -2):

remove `.` from urls.

Problem was in following file:

**File name:** apps/qnaBoard/urls.py

`from apps.qnaBoard.views.import writeAnswer` the `.` is there, remove it.

Comment: views are implemented with class. so it needs parenthesis.

Comment: yes got it, on which event or url call you get this exception?

Comment: @SeokJuHong: just run every py file by python command e.g. `python  apps/qnaBoard/views.py` and check if there is any `syntax error`

Comment: After your comment, I tried manage.py shell and I found there was a line of stupid code, `from apps.qnaBoard.views.import writeAnswer`

Comment: There was a dot between views and import. crap :( Anyway, many thanks to you!

Comment: Ok I will update my solution according to that. If you have any problem related to python you can reach to me by email vivekbsable@gmail.com or skype vivek.igp